# CORS-Issue in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: angularjs, rest, google-chrome

Could you please help me out in fixing the CORS-Issue in Firefox, Chrome, Safari. As my code is working fine in IE-11. When passing the Http GET request from the browser, it is giving null values in FF, Chrome, Safari. The following is the code that I am trying to execute:

```
$http.get(URL).success(function(data){})
              .error(function(data){});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing that can be 'fixed'. You need to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on the server side.

**How** you enable this depends on the kind of server. For node and express for example there are modules available that add the necessary headers to the http request and response cycle.